# Java Video Player

Tags: java, video, buffer, frame, codec

I need a java api, that cannot use JMF, to play video interpreted by the SO codecs but i want to retrieve the each frames in java code. Somebody know some?

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at [FMJ](http://fmj-sf.net/index.php).  It does *not* require the [Java Media Framework](http://java.sun.com/javase/technologies/desktop/media/jmf/) (JMF).

They have an [example](http://fmj-sf.net/ffmpeg-java/getting_started.php) at the bottom of the page that writes out the first 5 frames of the video to files, so you should be able to get to the individual frames.

Answer (score 2):

FMJ is very much out-of-date and JMF is a lost cause (yes one of those is IMHO). If you want something that works and will do exactly what you have described, try Xuggle. In their media tools examples they offer a simple player example using AWT / Swing.
http://xuggle.com/

Comment: Link down......

Comment: Yep, they got bought and started a new project under https://github.com/artclarke/humble-video Also the post is 6+ years old now.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with Java wrapper around FFMpeg, try [velvet-video](https://github.com/zakgof/velvet-video).

Code snippet to extract images from a video file:

```
IVelvetVideoLib lib = VelvetVideoLib().getInstance();
try (IDemuxer demuxer = lib.demuxer(new File("/some/path/example.mp4"))) {
    IDecoderVideoStream videoStream = demuxer.videoStream(0);
    IFrame videoFrame;
    while ((videoFrame = videoStream.nextFrame()) != null) {
        BufferedImage image = videoFrame.image();
        // Use image as needed...
    }
}
```

A more advanced example of video player implementation using velvet-video can be found [here](https://github.com/zakgof/velvet-video-player).

Disclaimer: I am the author of velvet-video.

Comment: Just linking to your own library or tutorial is not a good answer. Linking to it, explaining why it solves the problem, providing code on how to do so and disclaiming that you wrote it makes for a better answer. See: [**What signifies “Good” self promotion?**](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/182212)